# How to read the memory in a device using C# through TwinCAT?

Tags: c#, twincat, twincat-ads-.net

It is possible for me to access the memory of a device and read/write to it using C#? I know it is possible using TwinCAT. Is there a function in the library where I could access the memory through TwinCAT?

This is how I [access the memory through TwinCAT](http://infosys.beckhoff.com/english.php?content=../content/1033/tcsystemmanager/reference/ethercat/html/EtherCAT_Slave_AdvancedSettings.htm&id=)

Comment: Its very specific to the device. TwinCAT was Beckhoffs attempt at an EtherCAT (realtime ethernet programmable logic controller) and is based on a dual-OS (a realtime one running side-by-side with Windows Embedded). TwinCAT exposed an API that allows you to read/write to memory directly since this is much faster than going through an API that uses named addresses and allows the type of packet transport they use (it accepts a packet, adds data to it, and forwards it on). What device are you talking about?

Comment: I'm trying to access an EtherCAt junction box.

Comment: @Chris It is actually a prototype the company I'm working for is developing. I am testing this prototype to see if I'm getting the values I'm expecting in the memory.

Comment: @XTT Ah, I see, interesting! Since the system manager can do it, you should be able to too. Perhaps you could use the ADS debugger (http://infosys.beckhoff.com/english.php?content=../content/1033/tcadsamsspec/html/tcadsamsspec_tcadsamsdebugger.htm&id=) to find out what and how it accesses the memory of the slave.

Answer (score 1):

Absolutely, there's a C# library called *TwinCAT.Ads.dll* that accesses almost any device via ADS. How you communicate depends a great deal on what kind of device you're accessing. Each device usually has documentation that tells you what ports, indices and subindices you need to deal with.

Example:

```
var ads = new TcAdsClient();                  
ads.Connect( "10.0.0.155.1.1", 800 );
ads.WriteAny( 0xF020, 0x1, (byte)0xC );
```

That code connects to a BC9050 PLC with AMSNetId 10.0.0.155.1.1 over the network and writes one byte with the value 0xC to the memory of runtime #1 at %IX1.*.

If you need high performance access to a task's memory of a local TwinCAT installation, there's also a library called R3IO that gives you very fast direct memory access. It only exists in Twincat 2, though.

Edit: Seems that you want to read slave memory directly (which isn't usually done). Since the System Manager can do it, I would assume you should be able to too. Using their unsupported [ADS debugger](http://infosys.beckhoff.com/english.php?content=../content/1033/tcadsamsspec/html/tcadsamsspec_tcadsamsdebugger.htm&id=) you should be able to find out what ADS commands it issues to access the memory.

I would also think that, if you're using their ASICs, that the documentation for those might have more information regarding this.

When you have that information, writing up a C# program to read this should be pretty straight forward.

Comment: Thanks! I will see what I can do with the ADS debugger.

Comment: I am using TwinCAT 3 though. Can I use ADS debugger with TwinCAT 3?

Comment: @XTT Not sure, but I would assume that the ADS protocol has stayed the same. Give it a try!